# Multiple SSL Sites in one IIS 7.5 server

Tags: iis, ssl

I have read almost all the ssl threads there are about multiple ssl sites on one server.

most of them recommend buying a wildcard ssl, which i already have.

but now i purchased another ssl for a different root domain.
i know i need to bind it to a different ip address, but thats where it gets tricky.

I have 2 iis servers running behind a load-balancer.
I have configured a new zone in the LB with a new external IP address for the new site i need the ssl for.

I have configured the internal network card of both of the servers to have another internal ip address (so it now have 2 ip addresses).

but what should i do now?
what do i need to set in the binding for each of the websites?

So far in the wildcard ssl enabled websites i have configured in the binding the hostname (using the *.xxx.com trick), and in the ip-address i set to "all unassigned".
Do i have to change those aswell?
Can i just configure the new site's binding to listen only to the new ip address?

what is the complete step-by-step way to do this right?

thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, change the existing bindings to the specific address(es) that they'll be bound to - I've had bad experiences with mixing "all unassigned" and specific address binds on SSL.  Make the change to the existing sites first and make sure everything's working correctly before trying to add more sites.

Other than that, you've pretty much got it - just set up a binding for each site on the specific address with the specific SSL certificate for that site.

Comment: Do i need to set the HOSTNAME for the new site's ssl? because when its not wildcard you cant set it with the gui i think

Comment: No, not if it has the IP address all to itself - there's no need for a hostname specification.  However, if you do need to set a hostname for some reason, you [can do so via appcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: I just tried to change the "all unassigned", but then i figured i need to change the 1 "all unassigned" binding to 2 ip-address based binding because each of my IIS servers has a different internal IP...

When i did it and had 2 bindings with different IP's the site just wont load

Comment: Is it bound to the IP address that the name's resolving to (or that the load balancer is pointing at)? What error do you get?

Comment: it is bound to two diffrent IP's (the internal of each IIS), Im getting a not found error, like its not sending anything back

Comment: Do you mean a 404?  And does it immediately start working when you add the "all unassigned" binding back in?

Comment: Yes, i think its because i have multiple websites under the wildcard's ssl

Comment: Sure - did you add the IP-specific binding to each of them (with the correct host header), or just one site?

Comment: Ok it does work now! Someone missconfigured the load balancer :)